# how to patch a file of an ubuntu package in launchpad

Tags: launchpad, patch

I found a solution to a bug in one of the package but I'm unable to understand how to update the package.

The Code tab of the project at launchpad.net says 
"You cannot upload to this branch. Members of [Ubuntu branches](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches) can upload to this branch."

This might be a duplicate question but I didn't found any Beginner level guide to help me.

Answer (score 0):

On the bug report page, there should be a way for you or anyone else to post a message or a patch file -  post your patch there.

I don't think that most projects will allow just anyone to directly edit their code, going through the bug report page would be best.